# How do I show image in wpf datagrid column programmatically?

Tags: wpf, image, datagrid

I want to add two columns in wpf datagrid one image & one text columns dynamically.

Xaml code :

```
 <Grid><DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0" Name="grid" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" ></DataGrid></Grid>
```

Code Behind:

```
 DataGridTextColumn col = new DataGridTextColumn();
  col.Header =Text1;
  col.Binding =Text1;
  grd.Columns.Add(col);
```

How do I add image column?or show image in the column?

Please suggest

Dee

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Anvaka said, you can Use `DataGridTemplateColumn`.
In C# you can add create `DataGridTemplateColumn` as this, Here i have added a `CheckBox` in to the `DataGridTemplateColumn`.

```
DataGridTemplateColumn col1 = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
col1.Header = "MyHeader";
FrameworkElementFactory factory1 = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Image));
Binding b1 = new Binding("Picture");
b1.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
factory1.SetValue(Image.SourceProperty, b1);
DataTemplate cellTemplate1 = new DataTemplate();
cellTemplate1.VisualTree = factory1;
col1.CellTemplate = cellTemplate1;
datagrid.Columns.Add(col1);
```

Here Picture is a property of `ImageSource` type in the class which collection is assigned to `ItemsSource` of `DataGrid`.

Comment: I have tried this code.But it doesn't work for Image.

FrameworkElementFactory factory1 = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Image)); 

What else can I try?

Comment: Got this exception 'Image' type must derive from FrameworkElement, FrameworkContentElement, or Visual3D.

Comment: Your code is working.It has make the life easier.Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

Use [DataGridTemplateColumn](http://blogs.msdn.com/vinsibal/archive/2008/08/19/wpf-datagrid-stock-and-template-columns.aspx). Define cell template in `Window.Resources` and use [FindResource()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findresource.aspx) to set column's `CellTemplate` property.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Anvaka,

Thanks for quick reply.Can you please give me some example or code?

Comment: The links provided by you contains xaml code.I need to add the columns in the code behind(c#).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to Set an Image in a DataGrid Column HEADER, 
only programmatically, you can perform like this:

```
ImageSource image = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"C:/téléchargement.jpg", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));

Style style = new Style(typeof(DataGridColumnHeader));
FrameworkElementFactory factory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Image));
factory.SetValue(Image.SourceProperty, image);
factory.SetValue(Image.StretchProperty, Stretch.Uniform);
style.Setters.Add(new Setter { Property = TemplateProperty, Value = new ControlTemplate { TargetType = typeof(DataGridColumnHeader), VisualTree = factory } });

DataZone.Columns[5].HeaderStyle = style;
```

You can use this method for any type ( Ex : TextBlock , Label, ...), or create a more complex controlTemplate