# Need Xaml/C# image to DataGrid Explained

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I looked at the article at [WPF add datagrid image column possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15683314/wpf-add-datagrid-image-column-possible) and it looks fairly straightforward to add an image column to a datagrid. However one part I dont understand is the code line:

```
textColumn1.Binding = new Binding("YourBindingField");
```

Something similar appears in the MSDN help for Binding(string).
What does this string mean and where is it coming from? what am I binding to . I am completely lost on this and need help as to where I get this string from. I just have an array of image paths. is there a class i need to build that links them somehow.
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

"YourBindingField" is the **property** that you are binding to the column. 
It is the property of your data context which can be either a dependency property in your code behind, or a property in the view model.

Answer (score 0):

This line is setting the Binding of the control to the Property "YourBindingField" on the current data context.  WPF allows you to bind a controls value of an object that is set to the controls data context or the data context of one of its parent containers.